# htmlunit can not call post ajax requests

Tags: java, ajax, htmlunit

I have a webpage that fills a `datagrid` with post ajax requests like this

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://bss.bimser.com.tr/Handlers/eBADataGridHandler.ashx",
  data: '{"ID":"dgSearchTickets","Type":0,"Page":"2","FilterInput":[],"QuickFilterText":null,"SortedColumn":""}',
  success: function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
  }
});
```

When i try this with the below code i cant get html result; my code;

```
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        UnexpectedPage upage = webClient.getPage(webRequestPost);
        HtmlPage page = HTMLParser.parseHtml(upage.getWebResponse(), webClient.getCurrentWindow());

        WebRequest webRequestPost2 = new WebRequest(new URL(".../DataGridHandler.ashx"), HttpMethod.POST);
        webRequestPost2.setAdditionalHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        webRequestPost2.setRequestBody(DefaultValues.searchPagingJson2);
        page = webClient.getPage(webRequestPost2);
```

this code returns an error webpage. How can i get html info ?

**EDIT:**

```
page.executeJavaScript("var request = new XMLHttpRequest();\n" +
            "request.open('POST', 'http://bss.bimser.com.tr/Handlers/eBADataGridHandler.ashx', true);\n" +
            "request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');\n" +
            "request.onload = function() {\n" +
            "  document.getElementsByTagName(\"body\")[0].innerHTML = request.responseText;\n" +
            "  console.log(request.responseText);\n" +
            "};\n" +
            "request.send('{\"ID\":\"dgSearchTickets\",\"Type\":0,\"Page\":\"%s\",\"FilterInput\":[],\"QuickFilterText\":null,\"SortedColumn\":\"Sent Date\"}');\n");
```

I was able to solve the problem by executing the code above. Now the problem is without manual waiting `htmlunit` does not wait for the result. I tried this below

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.setAjaxController(new AjaxController() {
            @Override
            public boolean processSynchron(HtmlPage page, WebRequest request, boolean async) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In general HtmlUnit can do ajax requests.

Creating you own web request is not the design idea of HtmlUnit. Think about HtmlUnit more like a browser automated by your code. Have a look at the samples on the HtmlUnit homepage.

If you really like to create your own requests you are responsible for the whole request. This includes various headers for security or session information. Install a web proxy like Chares and watch the communication of the real page. Then you might be able to create a similar request. And have a look at the returning webpage maybe there is a hint for you (like the login is missing).

Comment: Please see the edit. There was a rare paging method in the website which posts DataGridHandler.ashx and server takes it from memory. This is way WebRequest didnt work. But now i have another problem.  I am doing multithreading jobs and i can not make sure page waits javascript. Plus i am sending **same** per thread thus i need to make it *deep copy*